# unexpected result in using fgets and strstr

Tags: c

I made following two codes for searching string **s2** in string **s1** and if **s2** is found in **s1** then the address of location where match is found is printed and  **s1** should be printed from location of match to last character of **s1**. if **s1="god is great"** and **s2="is"** then address of match as well **"is great"** should be printed.

```
CODE 1:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    char s1[80]="god is great",s2[10]="is";
    char *searchptr;
    searchptr=strstr(s1,s2);
    printf("%p\n%p\n",searchptr,s1);
    sprintf(s1,"%s",searchptr);
    puts(s1);
}

CODE 2:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    char s1[80],s2[10];
    char *aptr;
    printf("%s\n%s\n","enter a line","enter string to be searched");
    fgets(s1,80,stdin);
    printf("\n");
    fgets(s2,10,stdin);
    aptr=strstr(s1,s2);
    printf("%p\n,aptr);
    sprintf(s1,"%s",aptr);
    puts(s1);
}
```

In first code i have already initialized the string and its working but the second code is giving really unexpected result. It is giving the address of matching in every case(as i have tried) **aptr=0000000** .is there anything wrong in using **fgets** as in second code i want to take input from  keyboard?

Comment: Since when keyboards in the market become `TAB` free?

Comment: It's `int main(void)`. You're not free to change main's return type.

Answer (score 5):

`fgets` stores the `'\n'` - newline (entered when enter key is pressed) in the read buffer as well. So your search string `s2` becomes `"is\n"` which is not present in the `s1` to `aptr` is `NULL` and that is being printed.

You need to trim the `'\n'`  from `s2`, you can do that by

```
fgets(s2,10,stdin);
if(s2[strlen(s2)-1] == '\n')
   s2[strlen(s2)-1] = '\0';
```

Also, check for `aptr` not `NULL` before printing it.

Comment: it means i also didn't need that printf("\n") .It will automatically take me to next line

Comment: Yes. It will. No need of `printf`.

Comment: does getchar() also insert new line character?

Comment: @user17815, do `man getchar`